# Adding OpenGl framework into another framework Xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl, frameworks

I have a framework that I am building and inside the framework are files that rely on the OpenGL framework. When I build I get errors saying that all my OpenGL commands are undeclared identifiers due to the macros not reading correctly from the openGl framework. Any pointers?

Comment: @genpfault. why the edit?

Comment: [Boosting the SNR a bit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).  If you really want you can revert the edit.  I won't edit it out again.

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful. Undeclared identifiers sounds like an issue at compile-time. Frameworks are primarily a link-time feature; they also setup include search paths, but simply adding a framework to your project is not going to add the necessary `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>`, etc. to your code.

Comment: no problem @genpfault.  I found a workaround although it is a little strange. I am adding all the correct imports but when I change my base SDK from 10.9 to 10.8 it works. The strange thing is that when I add the framework to a project targeted for 10.9 it works. So there is some bug between Mavericks and openGL macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the work around after a couple of hours. If you are building a framework with openGL in it, you can not target it for 10.9. When I changed it to Lion, it works. Not sure if apple is aware of this bug. The stranger thing is that I can add the framework to a project targeted for Mavericks and it works just fine. SMH.